# How to replace Chrome with PhantomJS for use with Selenium and Conductor?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, conductor-framework

I am successfully using the Conductor framework to scrape data off a website. I use the Chrome browser and therefore I have installed chromedriver.exe in the root of my project.

To speed things up I want to replace Chrome with the headless PhantomJS browser. I installed PhantomJS as explained in the answer to this Stackoverflow question: [PhantomJS & Conductor Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875569/phantomjs-conductor-framework) and have changed the browser to Browser.PHANTOMJS in @Config.

Whatever I do however, I get no results.

I found no documentation how to setup PhantomJS for use with Selenium or PhantomJS.

The question [How to Implement Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS and Can we Use Sikuli with PhantomJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137871/how-to-implement-selenium-webdriver-with-phantomjs-and-can-we-use-sikuli-with-ph) did not help either.

**How to replace Chrome with PhantomJS for use with Selenium and Conductor?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trouble you are having appears to be due to an older version of the PhantomJS library included in Conductor.  The error when running PhantomJS can be found in [this imported issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8088) on the Selenium Github.  The remedy is to import a [fork](https://github.com/codeborne/ghostdriver) of PhantomJS which works with the newer releases of Selenium.

You can easily implement this by editing the `pom.xml` file and swapping

```
<groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>${phantomjs_version}</version>
```

with

```
<groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
<artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
```

Comment: as the creator of conductor, i can tell you that this solves the issue.  the fix [has been merged](https://github.com/conductor-framework/conductor/pull/23)  but might take a while for me to push a release.   my CI stuff got screwed up when i migrated hosts.

Comment: It worked. @sircapsalot Conductor is a truly great framework. It made me productive almost immediately without knowing much of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless chrome driver with selenium, as showed here:

https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python